# Replication of SAS glm in R

Tags: r, sas, regression

The problem statement on which I am working is I have to generate a regression model for an experimental setup where I have a treatment group and control group having equal number of members in both groups. I was able to do it easily in SAS. The dependent variable is continuous and independent variable has 2 levels 0 and 1 for controls and treatments respectively and has a few covariates as well. I wanted to get the lsmeans across different categories for my independent variable. Then,I was trying to replicate sas glm model in R. The code in sas was:

```
proc glm data=<dataname>
class <names of categorical variables>
model <dependent variable> = <Independent variable (factor with two 
                            levels)>*<categorical variable (3 groups)> 
                               + <Covariates 1>+ <Covariates 2>

/ss3 solution;

    LSMEANS <Independent variable 1>*<Independent variable 2>/
slice = <Independent variable 2> stderr pdiff out= ls_means_1  ;
run ;
```

I was able to develop a similar model in R. But I am having problem in generating the last output in SAS produced by `stderr pdiff` as I don't know how to do that in R or how SAS generates this output:

```
<categorical variable> DF Sum of Squares Mean Square F Value Pr > F 
group1                 1 165.858883     165.858883   26.87  <.0001 
group2                 1 54.831101       54.831101    8.88  0.0029 
group3                 1 60.638963       60.638963    9.82  0.0017
```

Can I get some help on getting the above output?

This is the code I used in R to replicate the above model in R.

```
library(emmeans)
model=glm(<dependent variable>~<Independent variable>:<categorical variable>+ 
                       <Covariates 1>+<Covariates 2>,data=<dataname>)

summary(model)
sub_cut_lsmean = emmeans(model,specs="categorical variable",by="Independent variable")
```

This gives me the same lsmeans as I get in SAS. But what do I need to do here to get the above output as well

Comment: http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/car/html/Anova.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this `emmeans(model, pairwise ~ Independent variable 1:Independent variable2)`

Comment: A direct solution is welcome, but please ensure you add context around it so your fellow users will understand how it solves the problem

Comment: You can use pairs(emmeans(model,specs='Independent variable', by  = 'categorical variable)). You will get the stderr pdiff at the desired categorical level instead of all the possible combinations if you use this

Comment: @KarnDeb please add the edits to your answer, not in the comments.